# SQL/PHP counting those who have the same number

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to make a Query that count those table that have the same post_topic Number to give
to create the "Post Count" for the topic.
i been searching didnt found a solution I'm forced post.

this is what i have to far

```
    $sqld = "SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM `posts`
  ORDER BY 'post_topic'";
```

I feel like i'm missing something. thanks guys.
i left the screenshot incase

DB info:

[image]

Comment: Based on what was said, I _think_ that you want: `SELECT post_topic, COUNT(*) FROM posts GROUP BY post_topic;` ? ... which will give a total for each `post_topic`.

Comment: This Worked Perfect Thanks dude. life saver

Comment: Indeed, if @PaulT. would post the comment as an Answer, we can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info, it seems that this is the needed query:

```
SELECT post_topic, COUNT(*) FROM posts GROUP BY post_topic;
```

That will give a total for each `post_topic`.